# Cardioid is simple closed

Tags: geometry, analysis, differential-geometry

I am trying to proof that, the curve (Cardioid) $y(t)=(cos(t)+c*cos^2(t),sin(t)+c*sin(t)cos(t))$ is a simple closed curve if c in [-1,1].

I have no idea how to approach this problem. I hope someone could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For given $c\in[-1,1]$ the curve is given by
$$\gamma_c:\quad t\mapsto {\bf r}(t):=(1+c \cos t)(\cos t,\sin t)\qquad(0\leq t\leq 2\pi)\ .$$
When $|c|<1$ we have
$$\bigl|{\bf r}(t)\bigr|=1+c\cos t>0,\quad{\rm arg}\bigl({\bf r}(t)\bigr)=t\qquad(0\leq t\leq 2\pi)\ .$$
This already shows that $\gamma_c$ does not pass through ${\bf 0}$, and each ray starting at ${\bf 0}$ contains exactly one point of $\gamma_c$. It follows that $\gamma_c$ is simple and winds once around ${\bf 0}$.

The case $c\in\{-1,1\}$ is somewhat special: Most of the curve $\gamma_{-1}$ consists of
$$\gamma_{-1}':\quad t\mapsto {\bf r}(t):=(1- \cos t)(\cos t,\sin t)\qquad(0< t< 2\pi)\ .$$
Here we again have $\bigl|{\bf r}(t)\bigr|=1-\cos t>0$ for all $t$, and the above remains valid for $\gamma_{-1}'$. In addition $\gamma_{-1}'$ does not pass through ${\bf 0}$, so that $\gamma_{-1}=\gamma_{-1}'\cup\{{\bf 0}\}$ is still simple.

Comment: "This already shows that  does not pass through 0, and each ray starting at 0 contains exactly one point of . It follows that  is simple and winds once around 0." But why do i know that each ray only contains one point of  ?

Comment: @WanyM: That's the force of the arg function. This function maps the rays bijectively to $[0,2\pi]$, up to $0\sim2\pi$.

Comment: Thank you very much!